# How to get current page number with PDFBox

Tags: java, netbeans, pdfbox

When the user is reading the pdf and finish to read this, and close the pdf, I need to save the last page that the user read before closing the PDF with PDFBox library 2.0.20

```
try {
      InputStream bos = new ByteArrayInputStream(lib.getPdf()); // lib.getPdf returns the pdf file in byte[] array.
      int tamañoPDF= bos.available();
      byte [] datosPDF = new byte [tamañoPDF];
      bos.read(datosPDF, 0 , tamañoPDF);
      OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream (button.getText());
      out.write(datosPDF);
      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ //setting an action to a button.
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(button.getText())); //the pdf is opened
            out.close(); //here I think I have to insert the code that save the page number
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(InfoDelLibro.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }

                    }
          });


    } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(InfoDelLibro.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: And, what is the problem with the code that you posted? Where are you stuck? Note that, it's unlikely they you'll be able to find out what page the user last read, or do something just before the user closes it, unless either you have written the PDF reader yourself (in Java, or another language), or the PD reader has some published API to get access to it. So first step would likely be to investigate the PDF reader that you're using and find out how you can control/query it, if that's possible at all.

Comment: Erwin, im using a library called PDFBox, but I think there is a way to find the number of page. I am reading the methods of this library, but i cant find any that can solve my problem :(

Comment: Pdfbox is a library you can use to manipulate the pdf. But it does not communicate with arbitrary pdf viewers to get to know the last page open.

Answer (score 0):

```
  fun extract(document: PDDocument?): String? {
    if (document === null) return null
    val totalPages = document.numberOfPages
    var pdfTextStripper = PDFTextStripper();
    var pageText: String = ""
    var array = JSONArray();
    for (i in 1..totalPages) {
      val rootObject= JSONObject()
      pdfTextStripper.setStartPage(i)
      pdfTextStripper.setEndPage(i)
      pageText = pdfTextStripper.getText(document)
      rootObject.put("pagenumber",(i).toString())
      rootObject.put("pageContent",pageText)
      array.put(rootObject)
    }
    return StringHandler.format((array).toString())
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How does your answer relate to the question? How does it determine _the last page that the user read before closing the PDF_?